# Does oomkiller kick in at overcommit ratio

Tags: linux

If I configure the following

```
/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory = 2
/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio = 50
```

What happens if a program tries to allocate 50%? Does it kill the actual program or does it choose another program with oom killer?

Comment: Sounds like your question would be a better fit for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks posted it there